# What does "if we thought about it" mean?

Tags: meaning

> "Ordinarily we believe that other human beings are conscious, and
>   almost everyone believes that other mammals and birds are conscious
>   too. But people differ over whether fish are conscious, or insects,
>   worms, and jellyfish. They are still more doubtful about whether
>   onecelled animals like amoebae and paramecia have conscious
>   experiences, even though such creatures react conspicuously to stimuli
>   of various kinds. Most people believe that plants aren't conscious;
>   and almost no one believes that rocks are conscious, or kleenex, or
>   automobiles, or mountain lakes, or cigarettes. And to take another
>   biological example, most of us would say, **if we thought about it**, that
>   the individual cells of which our bodies are composed do not have any
>   conscious experiences."

[Thomas Nagel , What does it all mean? p. 24]

I've got a questions to ask:

What does "if we thought about it" mean? Does it mean "In case of we thought about it"

Thanks

Comment: In the cited context, ***if we thought about it*** is more or less equivalent to ***if we were asked about it***. That's to say - what it "means" to include either of those ***optional*** elements is ***we don't normally think about it***. Which carries the strong implication ***it's not a very important question, we don't feel strongly about it.***

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say "not very important" -- at  most "not very relevant to our day to day lives."  Possibly because we just take it for granted, such as, "if we thought about it, creating money is one of the most important jobs the government does, as our economy would be impossible with barter."

Answer (score 2):

The writer is saying that if we turn our thoughts/minds to the subject, we would say....

Other ways of putting **if we thought about it** are:

> If we were to think about it
>   In the event that we thought about it
>   If we were to give it thought/consideration.

You could also say **in case we thought about it** as you suggest.

Comment: I don't think it's idiomatic to replace ***if*** by ***in case** we thought about it* in this exact context. I'd go along with *in **the [unlikely] event that** we thought about it*. But ***in case*** is normally equivalent to ***lest***, which simply doesn't make sense here.

Comment: Agreed! I wouldn't have put it that way either but I think OP had the idea!

Answer (score 2):

"If we thought about it" means that in the ordinary course of things, if someone just sprung the question on us, we wouldn't have an answer.  We would have to stop and think before we came to a conclusion.

But, if we did stop and think, we would say that.

Comment: So it means "on refrection"?

Comment: Err -- on reflection.   But yes.